# Datomic query with wildcard for partial string

Tags: wildcard, datomic

So, I'm not a DB guy or Dev, I'm a network and sysadmin. We had a guy leave and I'm trying to do this. I feel like it should be really simple like it would be in SQL so I must be missing something.

I'm running a query from the datomic console and I simply want to return entities that have similar values. My brain equates this to using a wildcard when searching in a document etc.

Example Query that works:

[:find ?e
 :where
 [?e :project/name "3000gtVR4"]
]

so this works perfect when the project name is known... I get the value I expect for the entity ID. But what if I want to see if there is a similar project name in the DB but I don't know exactly what it is... 3000gt* or *VR4 or something similar would work in many programs but I can't find a similar value that works in Datomic

[:find ?e
 :where
 [?e :project/name "3000gt*"]
]

NoGo... I've tried about a hundred variations and honestly alot of the Datomic stuff I am reading is well outside of my experience. I feel like this shouldn't require some massive query and defining variables etc...

You can reply with the Clojure syntax as well and I may be able to understand it enough to smash it into submission through a REPL session but please understand that I'm way out of my realm here.

Answer (score 1):

Datomic query is an extended form of Datalog, which has different concepts than traditional SQL.

Try:

> [:find  [?e ...]
>        :where [?e :project/name ?name]
>        [(re-matches #"3000gt.+" ?name)]]

[?e ...] returns a collection of entities.

[(re-matches #"3000gt.+" ?name)] uses the clojure function as a predicate.
Here is a good tutorial https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query.html

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same need, and the only reply here doesn't worked for me stating that `#` being a invalid input so I did this:

```clj
{:find  [?e ...]
 :where [[(re-pattern "3000gt.+") ?regex]
         [(re-matches ?regex ?name)]
         [?e : project/name ?name]]}
```

You need to do the functions call separately because [function expression clauses do not nest](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/query/query.html#function-expressions).

Comment: `#"3000gt.+"` is not a function call and therefore can be passed as an argument to `re-matches` within a function expression like this `[(re-matches #"3000gt.+" ?name)]`. Use of the `#` before a string is a regular expression pattern literal in Clojure. https://practical.li/clojure/reference/standard-library/regular-expressions/

Answer (score 0):

I found both the examples given here difficult to use because they were incomplete. It took me more than ten minutes to figure out in what context the other answers were executing their code fragments and how to modify their code fragments for my context. Here is a more complete example executed in the Clojure REPL in complete context so that the reader knows what fn is processing the query.

```
(require '[datomic.client.api :as d])
(d/q '[:find ?name :in $ :where [?e :molecule/name ?name] [(re-matches #"jz_.*" ?name)]] (db/get-db))
```

The `(db/get-db)` fn is one I defined that gets the Datomic database value.

The above is copied straight from my REPL and works. It returns:

```
[["jz_b"] ["jz_c"] ["jz_a"] ["jz_auto_b_141"] ["jz_auto_a_107"] ["jz_d"] ["jz_a:jz_b:jz_c:jz_d:jz_e"] ["jz_e"] ["jz_auto_b_3"] ["jz_auto_a_35"] ["jz_integral"] ["jz_auto_a_121"] ["jz_auto_a_3"] ["jz_auto_a_310"] ["jz_auto_a_442"] ["jz_auto_b_107"] ["jz_auto_a_141"] ["jz_auto_a_89"] ["jz_auto_b_35"] ["jz_auto_b_89"] ["jz_auto_b_310"] ["jz_auto_b_442"] ["jz_auto_b_121"]]
```